# org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression X and Y axis

Tags: java, machine-learning, dataset

dataset --> [[2019-05-01,4],[2019-05-02,9],[2019-05-03,13],[2019-05-04,17],[2019-05-05,21],[2019-05-06,25],[2019-05-07,29],[2019-05-08,33],[2019-05-09,37],[2019-05-10,41],[2019-05-11,45],[2019-05-12,49],[2019-05-13,53],[2019-05-14,57],[2019-05-15,61],[2019-05-16,65],[2019-05-17,69],[2019-05-18,73],[2019-05-19,77],[2019-05-20,81],[2019-05-21,85],[2019-05-22,89],[2019-05-23,93],[2019-05-24,97],[2019-05-25,101],[2019-05-26,105]];

I have a dataset like above where date is the x-axis and some random number which is incrementing everyday in y-axis.

How can I predict values for future dates using the SimpleRegression java class predict() method.

I got stuck here. Any ideas would help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have loaded the datapoints in some iterable collection, then you can use a similar type of code to predict:

```
public Iterable<DataPoint> getNextDataPoints(long returnTime, Iterator<DataPoint> dataPointRange)
        {
            long start = -1L;
            long stop = -1L;
            DataPoint first = null;
            DataPoint second = null;
            int count = 0;
            SimpleRegression simpleRegression = new SimpleRegression(true);

            while (dataPointRange.hasNext())
            {
                count ++;
                DataPoint dp = dataPointRange.next();
                if (second == null)
                {
                    if (first == null)
                        first = dp;
                    else
                        second = dp;
                }

                stop = dp.getTimestamp();
                if (start == -1L)
                    start = dp.getTimestamp();

                simpleRegression.addData(dp.getTimestamp(), dp.getDoubleValue());
            }

            List<DataPoint> ret = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();

            if (count == 1)
            {
                ret.add(first);
            }
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                ret.add(first);
                ret.add(second);
            }
            else if (count != 0)
            {
                ret.add(m_dataPointFactory.createDataPoint(start, simpleRegression.predict(start)));
                ret.add(m_dataPointFactory.createDataPoint(stop, simpleRegression.predict(stop)));
            }

            return (ret);
        }
```

Thanks to [kairosdb](https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb)

Another example [here](https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c6563dc968485000195cdc2#L88)

Comment: should it be a 'DataPoint' iterable collection OR it can be any iterable collection?

Comment: @ValarMathi If it is any iterable collection, then you can add the datapoints to your regression using the method regression.addData(..,..) .It accepts double datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
We can add the date in milliseconds in the X-axis to get the more accurate predicted data. 

Posting the whole code here.


============================================================
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.regression.SimpleRegression;

public class TestRegression {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SimpleRegression s = new SimpleRegression();
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        //s.addData(new Date(),3);
        //s.addData(3,4);
        s.addData(now.toEpochMilli(),5);

        now = Instant.now();
        Instant yesterday = now.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        s.addData(yesterday.toEpochMilli(),3);

        now = Instant.now();
        yesterday = now.minus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        s.addData(yesterday.toEpochMilli(),1);

        now = Instant.now();
        Instant 2daysFromNow = now.plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(s.predict(2daysFromNow.toEpochMilli()));

        now = Instant.now();
        Instant nextDay = now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(s.predict(nextDay.toEpochMilli()));
    }
}


============================================================
```